# Why my Highchart won't appear in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, highcharts

**Updated: I finally got it to work.I typed the jquery script before the chart script.**

**PLEASE VOTE UP! I was banned from asking questions.I'm in the middle of writing my PhD thesis. And it's very crucial that I have access to ask questions on this forum. Thank you!**

I'm totally new to HTML, I'm trying to write a simple code to have two charts on one page, so I tried to place a simple highcart, like the one in this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

in an HTML code, but my chart won't appear when I tested it in an HTML editor. Below is my HTML code. Also, how do I create two graphs on the same page with different data, do I repeat the same js code and replace "container" with another name?

**Updated code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test Chart </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">   

     $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                '1', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'h', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});

     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        <div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Do you need to include jQuery?

Comment: @j08691   I test it online at http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/. I don't get an error message I just get a blank page in the preview window. I have no idea what iQuery is?

Comment: Include jQuery. Look at the [fiddle setting](http://imgur.com/CdLRloH). To get started, add the following script tag in your page... `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: I'm writing this for a project written in Python that reads data from sensors connected to my Raspberry pi and store them in an SQL database. Then, I'll use the data from the database to create my graphs.

Comment: Include jQuery **before** Highcharts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include jQuery in your page as well, as the commenter said you can include it with this.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​`

Then you need to fix this typo:

`$(#'container)'.highcharts` should be `$('#container').highcharts`

Comment: what is jQuery. I apologize I'm totally new to this.

Comment: jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people write JavaScript. link here: https://jquery.com/

Comment: I did both suggestion, still no luck. I tried jQuery 2.2.0 and 1.9.1 which is in my fiddle settings

Comment: Could it be the online viewer I'm using! I'll try it on my Apache server when I go back home in few hours.

Comment: @Julia_arch whenever you see `$('#foo')` that is a jquery function. jQuery always uses `$ `so you can recognize it pretty easily.  `$('#foo')` selects the element on the page with `id="foo"`, just like in your example you are selecting the container and turning it into a chart using `$('#container')`.

Comment: Great, Thanks for the explanation. I just learnt all of the following in a matter of 4 months: Python, SQL, Apache, Linux and Raspberry pi. I had no programming experience before. I needed to finish this project in HTML, no time to learn html and js at this moment.

Comment: Anyone. I just tried it again no luck. I've been banging my head trying to get this to work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include 2 graphs on the same page you need to have

```
    <body>
      <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      <div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
```

And then create 2 graphs

```
$(#'container').highcharts({...});
$(#'container2').highcharts({...});
```

And set different data sources for each graph